# Cannot point domain to Amazon EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I want to point my domain name `edu3d.co` registered in bluehost to Amazon EC2 `54.206.125.84`.

I did following works but the browser still throws the error `www.edu3d.co’s server IP address could not be found.`

[image]

**Approaches I tried**

- I created records in Router 53 hosted zones.

|name     | type | value.       | 
|edu3d.co.| A.   | 54.206.125.84| 
|edu3d.co.|PTR|54.206.125.84| 
|edu3d.co.|NS|4 records| 
|edu3d.co.|SOA|{default one}| 
|www.edu3d.co.|CNAME| {public DNS address}| 
[image]

- I tested these records, they all show NOERROR
- I ssh my instance, it is working
- I ping my instance, it is working
- I changed the security group, to let HTTP inbound rules accept all ip
- I set the name servers in bluehost domain and have waited for 48 hours
  [image]
  How to deal with this question? Thank you.

Comment: Getting 200 with remote address 54.206.125.84:80.  Did you miss adding the nameservers?

Comment: @HithamS.AlQadheeb Thank you for helping!!! Yes, I added the name server in the bluehost. I would attach the screenshot.

Comment: I can access http://edu3d.co/ fine.  There is an unrelated issue due to linked assets using the IP instead of the hostname.   http://54.206.125.84/logs/ http://54.206.125.84/sidekiq/ ...

Comment: So that works for you? But I still cannot visit. Dont' know what to do..

Comment: Can take up to 72 hours to fully propagate

Comment: Ok, I will wait to see. Thanks

Comment: @HithamS.AlQadheeb It is working! Happy!!

Comment: Glad you have it sorted.  Dont forget to change the URLs to use hostname instead of IP.  Use CORS where needed (S3/API Gateway)

Comment: Sure, I will do that!